# Vite Uncaught TypeError: http.Agent is not a constructor

Tags: vite, deepl

I am trying to use deepl-node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepl-node on a Vue 3 app running on vite 5.0.11.

I am just using the example usage from the docs, but the app throws the following error

```js
import * as deepl from 'deepl-node';

const authKey = "---"; // Replace with your key
const translator = new deepl.Translator(authKey);

(async () => {
    const result = await translator.translateText('Hello, world!', null, 'fr');
    console.log(result.text); // Bonjour, le monde !
})();
```

```
deepl-node.js?v=2f8c41fd:2475 Uncaught TypeError: http.Agent is not a constructor
    at node_modules/deepl-node/dist/client.js (deepl-node.js?v=2f8c41fd:2475:18)
    at __require (chunk-P2LSHJDD.js?v=45007535:4:50)
    at node_modules/deepl-node/dist/index.js (deepl-node.js?v=2f8c41fd:3021:20)
    at __require (chunk-P2LSHJDD.js?v=45007535:4:50)
    at deepl-node.js?v=2f8c41fd:3566:16
node_modules/deepl-node/dist/client.js @ deepl-node.js?v=2f8c41fd:2475
__require @ chunk-P2LSHJDD.js?v=45007535:4
node_modules/deepl-node/dist/index.js @ deepl-node.js?v=2f8c41fd:3021
__require @ chunk-P2LSHJDD.js?v=45007535:4
(anonymous) @ deepl-node.js?v=2f8c41fd:3566
Show 5 more frames
Show less
```

Answer (score 0):

This specific error is caused by vite not polyfilling the `http` module, see [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036803/uncaught-typeerror-https-agent-is-not-a-constructor).

More generally, what you are trying to do likely does not work - the `deepl-node` library will only work on a full `NodeJS` backend, it is not designed for a frontend app (as you would leak your key in the source code which would be accessible to users). You need to put the translation code in some backend and add a call to it in your Vite project. See [this answer](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-node/issues/31#issuecomment-1638425713)